# Setting a cookie from a remote domain for local development

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, cross-domain, tornado

So I am trying to set up environment for local development to pull data from my dev server at `dev.mydomain.com`.

The tornado REST server serving data uses a cookie-based authentication.

To obtain the cookie I sent an AJAX post login request to the server (from the website at `localhost`), and the secure cookie comes back in a response. I can see that in the chrome console (network->cookies). It has the proper name, value, domain (`dev.mydomain.com`) and everything.

Yet, the cookie doesn't get set and the REST requests that follow fail. It is not cross-origin related. If I go to dev.mydomain.com and log in manually in another tab the cookie gets set correctly and all my subsequent requests sent from local domain work fine (since they grab the now-existent cookie).

All my requests contain this:

```
xhrFields: {
  'withCredentials': true
}
```

And this is how my tornado server sets the cookie:

```
self.set_secure_cookie(
  COOKIE_NAME, tornado.escape.url_escape(str(COOKIE_VALUE)),
  expires_days=1, domain="dev.mydomain.com"
)
```

**Any idea why the cookie doesn't get set if the login request comes from `localhost`?**

I tried mapping 127.0.0.1 to `foo.mydomain.com` (for whatever that's worth) but this doesn't help.

Also, I cannot grab the cookie with javascript. Tried `xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');`, yields null.

Comment: Could be a protocol mismatch. I am requesting from https://dev.mydomain.com, and running localhost on http.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it makes sense to me that if you set the cookie for `dev.mydomain.com` that it does neither work for `foo.mydomain.com` nor for `localhost`.

What happens if you do something like this:

```
self.set_secure_cookie(
  COOKIE_NAME, tornado.escape.url_escape(str(COOKIE_VALUE)),
  expires_days=1, domain=".mydomain.com"
)
```

`*.mydomain.com` might work then.

EDIT:

Actually, I checked over and over again, and I can't find an example where people used the argument 'domain' for `set_secure_cookie()` but instead this argument exists for 'set_cookie()', as stated in the [docs](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_cookie):

> Additional keyword arguments are set on the Cookie.Morsel directly.
>   See http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#morsel-objects for
>   available attributes.

If you are sure about using secure cookies, you should first get sure to use a cookie secret in your application settings

```
class Main(web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        settings = dict(
            cookie_secret = "xxxx",
        )
```

then try to set the secure cookie, without specifying the domain

```
self.set_secure_cookie(
  COOKIE_NAME, tornado.escape.url_escape(str(COOKIE_VALUE)),
  expires_days=1
)
```

Comment: I see - I was playing both with secure cookies and regular ones and nothing seems to work. I think I will roll wit this solution instead - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3342225/1731005. Maybe one really is not supposed to be able to access a cookie like that to store it (but only grab it once it has been stored on a the same domain as the server is operating on).